# Fill with Transparency in Built-In Sprite Editor

Tags: sprites, game-maker

When I imported an image for a sprite, I realized it had a white background. I went into the built-in sprite editor to remove it. I tried using fill as there was a transparent color in the color selector. It did not work. Is there a way to do this, or an easier way than erasing it all by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the color remover tool. It works just like the fill tool, but it removes the color and replaces it with transparency. It does not work perfectly, but it should do the job. Keep in mind when using it, it removes all of that color in the sprite.